# How do I turn off Firebase local serve hosting access logs?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

Using `firebase serve`, I can see `console.log()` messages from my Firebase Cloud Functions. Unfortunately, I'm also serving hosting and the log window is spammed with hosting access logs.

How do I turn off those access logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't see how to turn them off, but I can just run `firebase serve` in separate console windows...

`firebase serve --only functions`

`firebase serve --only hosting`

The hosting will find an open port to use, and it's separated from my functions logs.